# Use a WAR dependency in Gradle Android project

Tags: android, gradle, war

I have an Android project built with Gradle that uses maven dependencies. The JAR packages are well imported but I want to use a WAR and it doesn't seem to work. I thought adding "apply plugin: 'war'" would resolve the problem but if I put :

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'war'
```

I get this error:

```
Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
```

Is there a way to have a WAR dependency on a Android project?

Comment: WAR files are for Web application servers. How are you intending to use a WAR in Android development?

Comment: Why You want to add a war dependency to an android project? Applying a war plugin is like saying: "This is an android application, as well as backend".

Comment: The WAR contains some classes I want to use in my Android app, especially REST resources that would be useful for my code. But maybe you're right, it's not a good practice.